# Assessment task after job offer. What does it mean?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer, assessment

I got a job offer, which I accepted. But few days before the offer, the employers sent me one last assessment task to do (reachable via a link), and they said it won't affect my employment process. I haven't done it yet, and I feel kinda nervous. On one hand, they indeed gave me the offer before I do the test, but on the other hand, I am not sure what could be the purpose of such a test anyway? I searched a little to know about it, and it does not seem an easy one.

Update: I did the test. I think I did well in two sections, and not so well in the third. They kept their promise, however, and continued the employment process.

Comment: Have you considered asking the employer what the purpose of the task is?

Comment: @Jeroen They actually said something very briefly that I can not remember. Something like we need it for our records, or it is a routine. It was not clear to me, so I just did not memorize it. But they focused on the fact that I should not worry. I am not sure if it is a good idea to contact them and ask again. Do you think it is ok to do that?

Comment: Well if you want to know the answer to what it means, they are the only ones that can answer with certainty. We can make some guesses, but speculation will not really help.

Comment: @Jeroen I see. Thanks.

Comment: My assumption would be that it's to help them determine if they need to plan some additional training for you to help you get started in their environment quickly.

Comment: It may just be a type of "personality quiz", rather than testing your skills. They may want to just see what type of person you are. Those tests are mostly pseudoscience, but it shouldn't harm your offer in any way.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did the test anyway. Let's see.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Congratulations on your new job.

These kinds of tasks (after a job offer) can be used to learn a bit more about your abilities, and what kind of support and training should be provided to you in your first weeks/months at the company. It could also be used to help them decide which teams/projects you would be best suited to, or something like that.

But really, anyone here is just guessing. The only people who can answer this question are your employer. But it's up to you whether you want to query them about it, or just do the task, not worry about it (as they say), and then forget about it.

Comment: But that job should be done in the first days of employment (and especially be paid as it's part of the training)

Comment: @FooTheBar In principle yes but usually not worth making a fuss about. You putting in an hour there might also speed up your training by several days because it takes that long to organize the suitable training for you.

Comment: Thanks Gh0stFish. I took the second option (did the task, and now waiting  their response next week).